# Else / Else If not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

This code runs when i click on a piece of text. The first if works, but the second doesn't want to execute.

```
if (music = true) {
    music = false;
    $('#musicButton').html("Music: Off")
}
if (music = false) {
    music = true;
    $('#musicButton').html("Music: On")
}
```

I tried else if and else, but none seem to work.

Comment: Use `==`. Right now you're assigning to the variable `music` instead of comparing it. Also, `music = false` evaluates to `false`, which is why the second if doesn't execute.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` or `===` is *test for equality* ... your first if condition will ASSIGN true to music and execute the body, your second if will assign false to music, and never execute the body

Comment: first one works because you're assigning `true` to `music`, however you're doing the comparison incorrectly. you'll want to use `==` or `===` instead.

Comment: @Purag should i convert every = to ==?

Comment: `x = y` changes x to be the same as y, and always returns true. `x == y` compares x to y, and returns true if they are the same, false otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use an if else statement for this to cut back on repetitive code.  Additionally, you're assigning music instead of testing for it.  In JavaScript you must use the `===` operator to compare two items.  You really don't even need the `===` operator because you are checking if an item is true, so you can simply encapsulate your variable by `()`.

```js
music = true;
$("button").click(function () {
  if (music) {
      music = false;
      $('#musicButton').html("Music: Off")
  }
  else {
      music = true;
      $('#musicButton').html("Music: On")
  }
}).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="musicButton"></div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that comparison in most languages is done by double = ... 'x==y'.

Assignments are done with single '='

Answer (score 1):

= is used as an assignment operator. For comparison you should use == or ===

```
if (music === true) {
    music = false;
    $('#musicButton').html("Music: Off")
}
if (music === false) {
    music = true;
    $('#musicButton').html("Music: On")
}

if (music == true) {
    music = false;
    $('#musicButton').html("Music: Off")
}
else if (music == false) {
    music = true;
    $('#musicButton').html("Music: On")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code as below, you change it to false, before happening, also need to use === instead, so something like below may work for you:

```
if (music === true) {
    $('#musicButton').html("Music: Off");
    music = false;
} else{
   $('#musicButton').html("Music: On");
   music = true;
}
```